# multiple log in asp.net using sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i try this one, can't access the default file in login. I already checked the the database and tables they are the same. I'm trying to create multiple users but I can't login. What is the proper way of accessing multiple user?

```
if (Sessions.Current.authenticated != null)
    {
        if (Sessions.Current.authenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Admin/Default2.aspx");
        }
    }
}

protected void login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = txtUsername.Text.ToString();
    string password = txtPassword.Text.ToString();

    DataTable dtUser = DBConnector.getTable("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = '" + username + "' AND Password = '" + password, false);
    if (dtUser.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        DataRow dr = dtUser.Rows[0];
        Sessions.Current.authenticated = true;
        Sessions.Current.lastfirst = dr["Name"].ToString();
        Sessions.Current.Usertype = dr["userType"].ToString();


        Response.Redirect("Admin/Default2.aspx");
        Response.Redirect("web/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: beware sql injection issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all this code is atrocious. Anybody can use SQL injection to login to your website without using a password or username. Use parameterized queries instead.

Dont make queries in this way

```
DataTable dtUser = DBConnector.getTable("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = '" + username + "' AND Password = '" + password, false);
```

Now to the problem you are facing. i.e you are not hitting the Default page. This is because  of

```
Response.Redirect("Admin/Default2.aspx");
```

Once this code is executed the control leaves this page and goes to Page_Load event of Default.aspx2. So doesnt matter what you write after that, its not gonna get executed.